# Change class for last two rows in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a while loop that displays result from a MySQL query. I know how to change the output for the last row or an odd row but how can I change the output for the last two results?

For example I have a list of results in a 2x2 matrix with border-bottom: 1px on each result but I would like to display the bottom two without the border?

Comment: you can use CSS's [:nth-last-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild) and maybe save a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah just do it like this:

```
$result = //execute your query
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result;
$num_rows_different = 2;

$loop_counter = 0;
while ($loop_counter < $num_rows) {
   if ($loop_counter < $num_rows - $num_rows_different) {
      // with border
   } else {
      // no border
   }
   $loop_counter++;
}
```

I wouldn't use the CSS3 method due to its poor support...

Answer (score 4):

If you can use css3, it´s easy (I´ll use a list for the example):

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+2)
```

selects the last two `li`'s.

If you want to do it in php, you can count the number of results, add a counter in your loop and add a class to the last two items.

Comment: You should be able to implement a similar solution to this with jQuery, no?  That selector seems to work.

Comment: @Dereleased I haven´t tried it, but that´s what I would use for browsers that don´t support it natively.

Answer (score 0):

I like the CSS way, but you'll need to know the total number of items you're listing.  Then you can use a simple condition to check for that.

```
$total_items = [count of items];
$cnt = 0;
while($fetch as $row) {
    ...
    if(++$cnt > ($total_items - 2)) {
        // list with no border
    } else {
        // list with border
    }
}
```